# passing page details via GA4 page_view event

Tags: google-analytics-4

I have some specific details about each page I want to pass to Analytics 4.  Should I use push a standard `page_view` event with my extra parameters or a custom event like `page_details` or something (will that difference matter)?  Since GA4 automatically records this event when the page loads, will passing another `page_view` event apply to the current page view or will Analytics consider this an independent page view and make it inaccurately double the page views?

Comment: Yes you are right. Stop the auto collection from GA4's datastream. Make the tracking of page_view on your own using GTM or gtag()

Answer (score 2):

First, if you are sending `page_view` events manually you should set off your gtag auto pageview sender:

```
        gtag('config', GTAG_KEY, {
            'send_page_view' : false
        });
```

Having `send_page_view` enabled (by default ON) and sending manually events can result in double `page_view` events.

Then, about sending extra parameters, you could do something like this:

```
        gtag('event', 'page_view', { 'page_details' : 'your value here' });
```

Comment: I'm assuming that disabling the default page_view would also disable sending the enhanced measurement data as well?  So to push my page details on every page load, would it then just work to push these details via a separate, custom event?

Comment: No, as far as i know `send_page_view` will only affect the automatic `page_view` event that will be triggered by the `config`, so if you are firing your `page_view` event manually thats why i told you to disable that setting. You can find a vague post about this in the [official documentation.](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/pages#page_view_event)